# Netgear ProSafe FVS318G V2 keeps losing connection

Tags: switch, internet, netgear-prosafe

I have a Netgear Prosafe as per the title and as of yesterday when I relocated my office to a different room in the house it continually drops internet connection.

My ISP is Virgin Media and I am on the SuperHub 2 (which is not that super). I am using it in modem mode and using the prosafe as my firewall and switch.

When I can get a connection the best I have had a connection for is 42 minutes.  I then have to disconnect the WAN cable, reboot the switch, wait for it to come up fully then connect the WAN cable.

After a few seconds this then connects to the internet and I am able to browse, download and do anything a normal person would want \ need to do and then as I have mentioned it goes down again.

I previously saw a fix for this on Virgin Media forums but cannot find it again but was wondering if there are any specific things that I could do or check to ensure my rig is as it should be and to stop this from happening again.

The device specs are

Netgear Prosafe FVS318G-V2
Firmware 4.3.1-9

I have run a packet trace to see whats going on and it says that two of my machines are unreachable.

I have since removed these and had the same thing with my NAS too. I have also fixed IP addresses, no change.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Also, bear with me if I take a while in replying as I may have lost my connection.